# Ionic - data from email box returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I wrote code to create a user account using Ionic Framework with firebase but for some reason the email box returns an undefined while the password box works fine - they're both made the almost the same way.  Heres my HTML:

```
<ion-view view-title="Create Account">
```

```
<form name="form" novalidate="" ng-submit="createUser(form)">
  <div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Email:</span>
      <input type="text" ng-name = "email" ng-model="form.email" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" required>
    </label>

    <div class="error-container">
      <div ng-messages-include="error-list.html"></div>
    </div>

    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Password</span>
      <input type="password" ng-name = "password" ng-model="form.password" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" required>
    </label>

    <div class="error-container last-error-container">
        <div ng-messages-include="error-list.html"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <button class="button button-full button-positive" type="submit">
      Create Account
    </button>
</form>
```

Heres the controller class - the view calls this function in the controller when the form gets submitted:

```
  $scope.createUser = function(form) {
console.log("Email: " + form.email);
console.log(form.password);

var information = {
  email: form.email,
  password: form.password
};
Settings.createUser(form.email, form.password);
```

};

As you can see I have 2 console.logs.  The first one always returns 'Email: undefined' the second one returns whatever password I typed in, so the password works but not the email input box.  The call to Settings.createUser then proceeds to fail because email is undefined.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your $scope.createUser function, try accessing your elements like this,

```
this.email
this.password
```

Rather than `form.email` and `form.password`. Here is a link to a plunkr that I think accomplishes what you're looking for. Also, check out the AngularJS docs on forms, some good info there to help you along the way.

http://plnkr.co/edit/1ZFvLHLSXgkqQVNHCGMb?p=preview

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score 0):

OH - I figured it out...It was the ng-maxlength="20".  I realized if i typed asdf@hotmail.com it would accept it but not the input I was testing it with which was 'mattang5280@hotmail.com'.  The reason being was because the second one was longer than 20 characters therefore it would return undefined.